# How does one instantiate a block as an instance variable using ARC?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

What does one do to make something like this work?

```
void (^)(void) *someBlock = ^{
  //some code
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dmitry's answer is exactly right. Think of the block syntax as a C function declaration:

```
// C function -> <return type> <function name> (<arguments>)
void someFunction(void) 
{
  // do something
}

// block -> <return type> (^<block variable name>) (<arguments>)
void (^someBlock)(void) = ^{
    // do something
};
```

Another example:

```
// C function
int sum (int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

// block
int (^sum)(int, int) = ^(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
};
```

So just think of the block syntax as a C function declaration:
First the return type `int`, then the name of the block variable `(^sum)` and then the list of arguments types `(int, int)`.

If, however, you need a certain type of block frequently in your app, use a typedef:

```
typedef int (^MySumBlock)(int, int);
```

Now you can create variables of the `MySumBlock` type:

```
MySumBlock debugSumBlock = ^(int a, int b) {
    NSLog(@"Adding %i and %i", a, b);
    return a + b;
};

MySumBlock normalSumBlock = ^(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
};
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Awesome answer Johannes, thank you for that conceptual walkthrough

Comment: Happy to help :) It took my a while to wrap my head around the block syntax too :)

Answer (score 2):

Just block syntax

```
void (^someBlock)(void) = ^{
     //some code
};
```

Comment: Gave you an upvote for the answer, but I feel like the other one might help if its on top.  Thanks Dmitry