# Pass void (^)() as a completion handler

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a third-party library that performs some functions and then triggers a completion event once it is done. How do I pass a completion handler with void (^)() type?

```
obj.completionHandler = ???
```

The documentation does not give any examples just says that void (^)() type is accepted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`void (^)()` is a block type

so you can pass a block to it

```
obj.completionHandler = ^ {
    // code to execute when completed
};
```

Comment: Specifically, it's a block that takes no parameters and returns nothing.

Comment: See this answer to wrap your head around block type syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164928/how-does-one-instantiate-a-block-as-an-instance-variable-using-arc/16165317#16165317